# Editing Python's buit-in datetime module (just to to test how editing of built-in modules works). But it still behaves like it never changed

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging

Tried this on both Ubuntu and Windows

```
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:34:34) [MSC v.1928 32 bit (
Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.__file__
'C:\\Program Files\\python3810\\lib\\datetime.py'
```

Then edited the file. Just for a test replaced a return line from `isoformat` method of a `class date`

```
class date:
...
    def isoformat(self):
        """Return the date formatted according to ISO.

        This is 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

        References:
        - http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime
        - http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html
        """
        # return "%04d-%02d-%02d" % (self._year, self._month, self._day)
        return "%04d-%02d" % (self._year, self._month)

    __str__ = isoformat
```

Reloaded the Python shell, but the return of **str** is the same.

```
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:34:34) [MSC v.1928 32 bit (
Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.date.today()
>>> d
datetime.date(2023, 11, 16)
>>> d.__str__()
'2023-11-16'
```

So, is this even supposed to work like this, or something else have to be done?

Comment: There was a comment to a now deleted answer, it's basically answers my question. I don't remember the exact username, but if you will read this, you can post your answer and I will accept.

Comment: I just didn't know that this module written in Python being used just as a backup and there is a main _datetime written in C. So I removed the  `from _datetime import *` and it works as I was expecting. But, I've already put it back, since all of this just to understand how thing work with a modules written in Python.

Comment: This works perfectly for system wide python installation. Bit it breaks things for my Django environment. It crashes with `SystemError: initialization of _psycopg raised unreported exception` But no point investigating this, since I got the answer I wanted. The only I will try look into more is from where datetime importing _datetime written in C. Where it's located in Python installation.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the wrong track.
Try to use inheritance from datetime module objects, although it is not entirely trivial.

```
import datetime

class MyDate(datetime.date):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    def isoformat(self):
        return "%04d-%02d" % (self.year, self.month)
    __str__ = isoformat

if __name__ == '__main__':
    date = MyDate(1,2,3)
    print(date)
```